# How do I confine column max height to screen height? i.e let children "match_parent" size

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a "banner" displaying the weather over a carousel showing old projects I've worked on.
This is what I want it to look like (I cheated by using "Stack" to display it over the carousel):

[image]

I created a column and added the banner, followed by the carousel widget.
When displaying either one of them there is no problem, but when trying to display first the banner, with a fixed height, and then the carousel with an unbound size I get the following error:

> RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size
>   during layout.
>
> This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big
>   as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows
>   its children to pick their own size.
>
> The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
>
> RenderFlex#a0c6e relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   creator: Column ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
>   CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ←
>   AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#60a42 ink renderer]
>   ← NotificationListener ← PhysicalModel ←
>   AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← ⋯
>
> parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use
>   size) constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=683.4) size:
>   MISSING direction: vertical mainAxisAlignment: start mainAxisSize: max
>   crossAxisAlignment: center verticalDirection: down The constraints
>   that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
>   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity) The exact size it was
>   given was: Size(411.4, Infinity)

This is what is displayed on device:

[image]

I think I understand the problem, but I can't find a way to constrain the second child (carousel) to the remaining screen area.

Here is the code:

```
//main "App" build

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final weatherWidget = WeatherWidget();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          weatherWidget,
          CarouselWidget(getCarouselImages()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

// banner widget build

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (_startLocation == null) {
      print("d/ Error: No start location fetched!");
      return Container();
    } else {
      return Container(
       color: Color(0xFFFF00FF),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 40, bottom: 32),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
             'Uppsala',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text(
              'temp: -5.22',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  } 

//Carousel Widget build

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      child: Carousel(
        images: _images,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        showIndicator: false,
        boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you know how to handle this situation please share below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

When working with flex widget such as row/column you can wrap a child in a "Flexible"-widget.

If no parameters are set for the Flexible it will consume all the available space left of its parents container.

This is the only change needed from the previous code:

```
//main "App" build

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final weatherWidget = WeatherWidget();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          weatherWidget,
          Flexible(   //<--Wrapped carousel widget in a Flexible container
            child: CarouselWidget(getCarouselImages()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrapping the Container in a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) is a better option than just limiting it to screen height, then everytime your content overflows, it will be scrollable.

Comment: Wrapping the column in a singleChildScrollView does not change the outcome.
I still get the "bject was given an infinite size" error.  ```SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            weatherWidget,
            CarouselWidget(getCarouselImages()),
          ],
        ),
      ),```

Comment: Besides, my intention is not to size the second child larger then the available space left after the banner have been rendered.
There must be a way to set a widget to fill the the remaining parant area? right?